# ocaml variant types manipulations

Tags: ocaml

I have a variant type like this:

```
type score = 
    InInteger of int
    | InFloat of float ;;
```

Now, given two scores (`InInteger(5)` and `InFloat(5.5)`), I want to add, subtract them etc..

How can this be done?

PS - I'm a newbie to OCaml.

Edit::

More specifically:

How does this work?

```
let n = InInt(2);;
let m = InFloat(3.2);;

let var = InFloat(float n +.  m);;
```

Comment: (Let us know if this is homework so we don't give away too much stuff you're supposed to figure out.)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. This is not directly out of my homework, although an answer to this question will help me towards solving a question. I would really appreciate an answer on how +. operator works, and how  InFloat (float i1 +. f2) is a valid expression. (ref pad's answer)

Comment: @Gitmo: You edited example is wrong; it supposes to be `let var = InFloat(float 2 +. 3.2)`. Regarding `(+.)` operators on `float`, Jeffrey's comment on my answer is a great explanation.

Comment: By the way, semi-colons aren't necessary except in the `ocaml` REPL (to tell it when to stop!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, discriminated unions require their identifiers starting with upper cases:

```
type score = 
    InInteger of int
    | InFloat of float
```

Second, you can define an `add` function on this datatype by pattern matching all possible cases and returning appropriate values:

```
let add s1 s2 = 
    match s1, s2 with
    | InInteger i1, InInteger i2 -> InInteger (i1 + i2)
    | InInteger i1, InFloat f2   -> InFloat (float i1 +. f2)
    | InFloat f1, InInteger i2   -> InFloat (f1 +. float i2)
    | InFloat f1, InFloat f2     -> InFloat (f1 +. f2)
```

Comment: HI pad, I was trying something similar. But I don't understand the "+." operator. The example given here - http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual003.html#toc7 is also doing something similar. Can you please explain how the +. operator works?

Comment: OCaml is a strongly typed language, but it infers types so you generally don't have to specify them.  One way it does this is by knowing the parameter and return types of all functions.  To make this work, you need to have two different functions for adding ints and for adding floats.  So, (+) is the function for adding ints and (+.) is the function for adding floats.  There are other ways to handle different kinds of numbers with type inference, but this is the way OCaml does it.

Comment: Thanks! Coming from imperative languages (and ideas like operator overloading), it simply didn't occur to me that +. is an operator for floats.

Answer (score 3):

`+.` will add `float`s only, and `+` will add `int`s only. That's all there is to it! If you've got `float`s or `int`s wrapped inside your union type, you'll have to use `match` per pad's answer to get them out, then convert the plain numbers within.